# Impact of memory allocation on multi-threaded performance

Tags: c++, memory-management

Does memory allocation in multiple threads in modern C++ compilers cause a global lock access? How much does that vary between compilers and operation systems? How much benefit is there to putting small amounts of data in a pre-allocated global array (less clean, less convenient) instead of dynamically allocating it when needed by individual threads?

Comment: This really depends on the language, the design, the requirements, the use-cases, the frameworks used, etc. In short, *much* to broad to be answered really.

Answer (score 1):

All threads share a common virtual address space, so any memory allocation from the heap (malloc or new) will result in an update to the virtual address spaces used by all threads. How this is implemented will depend on the operating system as well as the compiler.

If the allocated memory only needs function scope and isn't too large, then it could be allocated using alloca() (or _alloca()), which allocates from the stack, which would be a thread and function local instance of that allocated memory.

In the multi-threaded programs I've written, I've used message and/or buffer "free" pools that are allocated at startup, then have the threads "allocate" and "free" the messages and/or buffers from the "free" pools.